# work with uploaded file in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

i want to post data with image to controller in yii2 but i had error like :
this is the model:

```
namespace app\models;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadForm extends Model {

public $imageFile;

public function rules() {
    return [
        [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
    ];
}

public function upload($data) {
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $this->imageFile->saveAs('@frontend/web/traviaAssets/agency/' . md5($data) . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }

 }
```

controller :

```
  $model = new \yii\web\UploadedFile();
   if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
       $model->imageFiles = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, $_FILES['imageFile']);
 }else{
      return false;
    }
```

**post the image file with with name of imageFile in form but i have this error:**

```
Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
Calling unknown method: yii\web\UploadedFile::formName()
```

Comment: Your model is UploadForm, not UploadedFile.

Answer (score 0):

UploadedFile [getInstance](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstance()-detail) method should contains model and attribute.

Use this code in controller:

```
$model->imageFile = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
$model->upload('someData');
```

Comment: error that i got Calling unknown method: yii\web\UploadedFile::upload()

Comment: You tries call `upload` method of UploadedFile model. You write `upload` in model `UploadForm`. `UploadForm::upload` you should call.